# Set footnote justification in minipage

Tags: tables, footnotes, minipage, acmart

I'm using the `acmart` class to write an article, and I've followed the manual's suggested means of including footnotes in a table. However, the footnotes are centred in the minipage, which I find ugly. Is there a way to left-align them?

Here is an example of a table with footnotes to illustrate:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,authordraft]{acmart}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\caption{Team statistics}
\label{tab:team-stats}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
% \raggedright here makes no difference
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
     Name & Height\footnote{I didn't have a tape measure to hand, so I asked each person their height. They may have been lying.} (cm) & Age (years)\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Team A}}\\
    Alice   & 190 & 12\\
    Bob\footnote{Standing in for Bart}
            & 175 & 11\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Team B}}\\
    Clare   & 175 & 13\\
    David   & 165 & 12\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

which gives
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not load [acmart](https://ctan.org/pkg/acmart), the `tablenotes` are not centred (but of cause still ugly). So, obviously, [acmart](https://ctan.org/pkg/acmart) or one of the packages it loads, do some nasty redefinition. To correct the bad spacing of the caption, you can use the command

```
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}
```

in the document preamble, because [acmart](https://ctan.org/pkg/acmart) loads the [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. An easy solution to the centring problem, is to use [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable), see the second example. Also, use the command `\centering` inside `\table`-environment, unless you want additional vertical space above and below the table.

**Standard article class, without [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable)**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Team statistics}
\label{tab:team-stats}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
% \raggedright here makes no difference
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
     Name & Height\footnote{I didn't have a tape measure to hand, so I asked each person their height. They may have been lying.} (cm) & Age (years)\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Team A}}\\
    Alice   & 190 & 12\\
    Bob\footnote{Standing in for Bart}
            & 175 & 11\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Team B}}\\
    Clare   & 175 & 13\\
    David   & 165 & 12\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**With [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable)**

Luckily, [threeparttable](https://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) typeset the table notes correctly, even if you are using [acmart](https://ctan.org/pkg/acmart), which is demonstrated in the updated example. I have changed the layout of the table a bit, with fixed width `w`-columns from [array](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) and two lines headings using [makecell](https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) (a highly recommended package. (You should avoid long footnotes in narrow tables.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}


\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}[c]
\caption{Team statistics\label{tab:team-stats}}

  \begin{tabular}{@{}wl{1.5cm}*{2}{wr{1.5cm}}@{}}
    \toprule
     \makecell{\\Name} & \makecell{Height\\(cm)\tnote{a}} & \makecell{Age\\(years)}\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Team A}}\\
    Alice   & 190 & 12\\
    Bob\tnote{b}
            & 175 & 11\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\textbf{Team B}}\\
    Clare   & 175 & 13\\
    David   & 165 & 12\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\item [a] I didn't have a tape measure to hand, so I asked each person their height. They may have been lying.
\item [b] Standing in for Bart.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I hadn't thought this was specific to the class file, but maybe it is. I've made the example a MWE. FWIW this is also on Overleaf. You're right about the clash of narrow tables and long footnotes but my real use cases are typically wider than the mock example, so your solution works very well, thanks.

Comment: I have corrected the answer, because I see that you have provided an MWE. threeparttable solves the problem, and of cause it is possible to hack into acmart, but it loads a ton of other packages so it is difficult to find the real sinner.

Comment: Thanks @Sveinung. `acmart` seems to uglify a few other things compared to your `article` example, including the spacing after the caption. But I see that's covered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1937/60034

Comment: @beldaz It is threeparttable that prettify the spacing, I agree that acmart adds to much space after the caption. Probably, it load the caption package, so  you can correct the spacing. But acmart destroys the nice spacing of threeparttable.

Answer (score 0):

The centered display of footnotes in minipages appears to be an intended change of the acmart style. Boris Veytsman just explained this [on GitHub](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/449#issuecomment-932653376) to me:

> This is the intended behavior since 2016. The file says:
>
> ```
> % \begin{macro}{\@mpfootnotetext}
> % \changes{v1.13}{2016/06/06}{Made minipage footnotes centered}
> %   We want the footnotes in minipages centered:
> ```
>
> I think this behavior was requested by ACM designers. I do not recommend you to change it in your own paper, but if you insist, here you are (again, I do not guarantee the conference committee or journal editor will like it):
>
> ```
> \makeatletter
> \long\def\@mpfootnotetext#1{%
>   \global\setbox\@mpfootins\vbox{%
>     \unvbox\@mpfootins
>     \reset@font\footnotesize
>     \hsize\columnwidth
>     \@parboxrestore
>     \protected@edef\@currentlabel
>          {\csname p@mpfootnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
>     \color@begingroup%\centering - commented out centering footnotes
>       \@makefntext{%
>         \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
>     \color@endgroup}}
> \makeatother
> ```